# Laravel how to pass request from controller to resource collection?

Tags: laravel, api, controller, backend

I will pass a parameter in the request. The query won't change. How can I pass the request to SurveyResouce

```
public function getAllSurveys(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $surveys = DB::table('surveys')
                ->select('id', 'survey_name')
                ->get();
    return response()->json([
               'error' => false,
               'data' => SurveyResource::collection($surveys)
           ],
}
```

I want get the request parameters in the resource

```
public function toArray($request) {
        $controller = new SurveyController(new SurveyRepository());
        return [
            'question' => $request->has('ques') ? $request->input('ques'):'',
        ];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by directly using `request()` helper function. Like `request('parameter');`

Comment: is there any other way? let say, I tried  SurveyResource::collection($surveys)->with($request) . but it is not working

Comment: finally solved with SurveyResource::collection($surveys)->additional(['ques'=> $request->input('ques')]) .